# writing a loop to produce a dataframe and a matrix

Tags: r, loops

I want to produce a loop for the follow

```
a<-DF[1,]
mymatrix1<- as.matrix(a)
```

So my next line, doing it manually would be

```
b<-DF[2,]
mymatrix2<-as.matrix(b)
```

and next

```
c<-DF[3,]
mymatrix3<-as.matrix(c)
```

and so on. I have 800 rows. I am sure with the power of r this does not need writing out 800 times.

Comment: I don't know what benefits you'll have with `mymatrix1`, `mymatrix2`... which you'll not have in `DF[1, ]`, `DF[2, ]`..

Comment: Try `lapply(split(DF,seq_len(nrow(DF))),as.matrix)`. The real question however is why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(DF)){
 assign(paste0('mymatrix',i),DF[,i])
 }
```